# LaTeX template crashes when including package

Tags: packages, colortbl

I have downloaded a LaTeX template I need to use for a conference submission, which is found [**here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbx31ridur4jvj3/egPublStyle-conf2014.zip). I presume that the template is well written and compatible with *any* extra package I want to use.

However, I figured out that it crashes somehow with the `colortbl` package, just adding `\usepackage{colortbl}` in the `EGauthorGuidelines-body_with_teaser.inc` file (included in the template I linked above).

I am getting the following error:

> ! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.
>
> to be read again>
>
> \cr
>
> l.44
>
> There should be exactly one # between &'s, when an
>   \halign or \valign is being set up. In this case you had
>   none, so I've put one in; maybe that will work.

Despite this, the final PDF is well generated. However, it is annoying not to know what is exactly going on (plus constantly seeing the red warning sentence everything I compile).

Does anybody know how can I fix this? Is the error due to an error in the template files? Or in the actual package?

---

**EDIT:** As the comment below days, looks like the trouble is with the redefinition of `tabular` inside the class I use. Thus, I update the question. Is there any alternative to `colortbl` to colorize a table cell?

Comment: Your class redefines `\tabular` and this is probably the source of the problem (but I didn't test it).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You seem to be right, I've updated my question. Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure, you wanna use colortbl for a scientific paper?

Comment: I haven't looked at this particular conference class, but historical evidence would suggest that your presumption is somewhat optimistic.

Comment: @yo' every scientific paper should have red and purple ruled tables. That's why I made the package.

Comment: The cause is a strange redefinition of the way the authors are typeset.